# Maven transient dependency not brought in

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, dependency-management

Are transient dependencies that specify the classifier tag as a part of a profile not brought in by default?

To be more specific I have a project A that defines a dependency as follows:

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>com.dependency1</groupId>
     <artifactId>dependency1</artifactId>
     <version>12</version>
     <classifier>${os.classifier}</classifier>
</dependency>
```

and a profile that specifies `${os.classifier}`

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>x86</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <os.classifier>x86</os.classifier>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>x86-64</id>
        <properties>
            <os.classifier>x86-64</os.classifier>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

When I depend on project A from project B, `com.dependency1` is not brought in. Is there something I'm missing or is this the default behavior?

Comment: have you tested what happens if you leave classifier out? I would think that dependencies with classifiers are only brought in if the classifier is used throughout the chain.

Comment: yea, leaving it out in project A doesn't work since it doesn't bring in the jar as a dependency (this breaks project A's build)...unless you meant something else when you said "leave classifier out".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The transitive dependency was actually being brought in. There was nothing wrong with my setup. All I had to do was to force re-import dependencies from project B.